# How to find strings between square brackets and wrap them in a CSS class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following paragraph:

> deemed to be safe and effective for fat reduction by about 20% at
> certain body sites. As a medical procedure, cryolipolysis is a
> nonsurgical alternative to liposuction.   [gallery ids="16,15,14"]

How can I find all strings in a `[ ]` and wrap them in a `preferred class`?

```css
.hidden{
   display:none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="post-paragraph">The degree of exposure to cooling causes cell death of subcutaneous fat tissue, without apparent damage to the overlying skin.The method has a low rate of complications, and is deemed to be safe and effective for fat reduction by about 20% at certain body sites. As a medical procedure, cryolipolysis is a nonsurgical alternative to liposuction.   [gallery ids="16,15,14"]</p>

<p class="post-paragraph">The degree of exposure to cooling causes cell death of subcutaneous fat tissue, without apparent damage to the overlying skin.The method has a low rate of complications, and is deemed to be safe and effective for fat reduction by about 20% at certain body sites. As a medical procedure, cryolipolysis is a nonsurgical alternative to liposuction.   [gallery ids="23,22,21,20"]</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find text and wrap that contain with `div class hidden` like below.

```js
$('p').each(function(index, element) {
  var str = $('.post-paragraph').text();
  var start = str.indexOf('[');
  var end = str.indexOf(']', start) + 1;
  var text = str.substring(start, end)
  $("p:contains(" + text + ")").html(function(_, html) {
    return html.split(text).join("<div class='hidden'></div>");
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="post-paragraph">The degree of exposure to cooling causes cell death of subcutaneous fat tissue, without apparent damage to the overlying skin.The method has a low rate of complications, and is deemed to be safe and effective for fat reduction by about 20% at certain
  body sites. As a medical procedure, cryolipolysis is a nonsurgical alternative to liposuction. [gallery ids="16,15,14"]</p>

<p class="post-paragraph">The degree of exposure to cooling causes cell death of subcutaneous fat tissue, without apparent damage to the overlying skin.The method has a low rate of complications, and is deemed to be safe and effective for fat reduction by about 20% at certain
  body sites. As a medical procedure, cryolipolysis is a nonsurgical alternative to liposuction. [gallery ids="23,22,21,20"]</p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lots shree, it is working perfectly as I needed